# Does the Barnes Hut Tree need to be recreated each iteration of a loop

Tags: algorithm, simulation, physics, game-physics

I'm coding an application which is required to perform an n-body simulation between a few hundred particles which are constantly in motion. The application has real time requirements and thus the algorithm performing the simulation needs to be fast.

I've done a fair amount of research on the matter and have come to the conclusion that the Barnes Hut algorithm would be most suitable for my needs, it seems very efficient for large particle sets.

http://arborjs.org/docs/barnes-hut  gave a very clear explanation on how the algorithm worked, but as the title implies, I'd like to know whether the tree needs to be recreated for each iteration, considering that the particles used in the simulation are always dynamically in motion. And if the tree does need to be recreated, how does one do it in the most efficient (in terms of processing power and memory) way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually with motion based indexes there is no "update" for the index after movement has occurred and you must rebuild the entire index.

The Barnes Hut Tree is the same and will have to be rebuilt.  Here is an [example](http://iss.ices.utexas.edu/?p=projects/galois/benchmarks/barnes_hut) I found online with a code outline of the process.

This is one of the reason so much effort has gone into build optimizations for things like the KD-Tree, and I'm sure the Barnes Hut has the same. Also, I'm sure there is research on dynamically updating, but most of the time these implementations are much harder than a simply rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late on answering this question. Guess I had never worked on this problem then. But not that I have been looking into it for sometime now, I can share some insight. What @greedybuddha is saying is mostly right, but they are tricks and techniques to prevent creating the tree entirely every time step. As usual these techniques with their own overheads (memory footprint etc) and necessary trade-offs need to be made. Also, it may not be possible to apply them in all situations.

1. **Allocate enough memory upfront to handle octree of a given depth. Deallocate the memory only when all timessteps have finished.** For example suppose for all n-body input data sets you are going to use, you know that your Octree will never go beyond a depth of say 10. In that case it is easy to figure out how many maximum nodes you octree might have(usually its a geometric progression sum). By doing a bit of bookkeeping(valid child indexes of each node) for every octree node, it is easy to reuse this buffer to fill in octree nodes without needing to allocate/deallocate octree nodes every timestep. Clearly the likely overhead here is that you might be wasting lot of memory but then you gain performance by not doing allocation/deallocation every timestep
   Usual way of going about bounding the number of octree levels is to allow  multiple bodies per leaf node (last level of octree or smallest cell size of octree grid)
2. **Create a new Octree only when needed**: It is possible to think about a situation where octree doesn't change for some series (burst) of timesteps and then it changes and the pattern repeats. This can happen only when bodies positions change insignificantly over a timestep burst such that octree structure remains the same during that burst. And in what situation will bodies move slowly - when the chosen timestep size is pretty small, forces exerted + initial momentum on bodies is small. How to dynamically figure out such bursts is a difficult problem. This is a more tricky technique and I dont know whats the easy way to do this. This requires some insight of timestep granularity, initial velocity/acceleration of the bodies and kind of forces the bodies are dealing with.